# How do i convert a string with the combination of text and number to an int type in java?

Tags: java, android, int, hex

How do i convert for example A0 into an int? And how do i then combine 0x with A0 as an int in java? My task requires me to use int as the data type. Thanks

Comment: So you want to convert hex to decimal?

Comment: So what is your expected output after converting  A0 into int?

Comment: my expected output would be 0xA0 in an int data type after combining 0x with A0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wanting to convert a Hex value into an `int` value for this you can use the `Integer` method `decode()`.

The conversion can look like this:

```
int i = Integer.decode("0xA0");
```

or

```
int i = Integer.decode("#A0");
```

in which case the result will be:
i = 160

If you wise to convert an `int` value back to Hex form use the `Integer` method `toHexString()` like this:

```
String s = Integer.toHexString(i);
```

This will give you s = "a0".

For more information on the conversions take a look at the java docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String)

Comment: Though OP mentions String as input but still seeing the alphabet (a~f) may have caused the assumption, if so then simple `int value = 0xA1` is valid , note that `0xA1` is not enclosed within " I.e. it's not a string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it did solved my question.